# Making a DLL in SQL which call WCF Server Error : Could not find default endpoint element that references contract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm searching for a solution from 2 hours, so I give up and post here.

I have a C# 3.5 DLL created. It's goal it soooooo easy :

```
public static string CallWsMethodClient(string sXMLSettings, string sXMLIn)
    {
        try
        {
            WS_Generic.ServiceClient serv = new WS_Generic.ServiceClient();
            return serv.CallWsMethod(sXMLSettings, sXMLIn);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            XElement xRootNode = new XElement("ALL_XML_OUT");
            xRootNode.Add(new XElement("DLL_ERROR_MESS", e.GetType().Name + " - " + e.Message));
            xRootNode.Add(new XElement("DLL_ERROR_STACKTRACE", e.StackTrace));
            xRootNode.Add(new XElement("DLL_ERROR_INNER", e.InnerException));
            return xRootNode.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I have a service reference to a webservice (WS_Generic.ServiceClient).

My objective is to import this dll as assembly in SQL Server 2008R2, and call the method from SQL in order to call the web sevice.

I import the DLL with this command :

```
create assembly [blabla]
```

from 'xxxx\blabla.dll'
with permission_set = unsafe

I create the stored procedure with :

```
create function CallWsMethodClient(@sXMLSettings nvarchar(max), @sXMLIn nvarchar(max))
      returns nvarchar(max) external name blabla.[WCF_SQL.WcfClient].CallWsMethodClient
```

And when I execute my stored procedure... TADA !

```
<ALL_XML_OUT>
  <DLL_ERROR_MESS>InvalidOperationException - Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'WS_Generic.IService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.</DLL_ERROR_MESS>
  <DLL_ERROR_STACKTRACE>   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
   at WCF_SQL.WS_Generic.ServiceClient..ctor()
   at WCF_SQL.WcfClient.CallWsMethodClient(String sXMLSettings, String sXMLIn)</DLL_ERROR_STACKTRACE>
  <DLL_ERROR_INNER />
</ALL_XML_OUT>
```

I just want to die... Anybody have an idea ?

Of course, the config file of my dll is name_of_dll.dll.config.

May the dll is in memory, so I have to code in the dll my endpoint ? Bu the problem is I have to recompile it each time the url of web service change.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "the config file of my dll is name_of_dll.dll.config" - you do realize that DLL's dont' use config files, right?  Unless you have written something custom in your DLL.

Comment: When you add a service reference to your dll, Visual Studio create a config file for the dll, to configure endpoints. Its name is app.config in VS, and name_of_the_dll.dll.config after compilation.

Comment: True.  And when you create a class library (DLL) project in Visual Studio it includes an app.config file as well - doesn't mean that the DLL actually uses it.  I haven't run managed code in SQL Server, so it *might* be different in that case, but I use DLLs and WCF extensively, and I've always had to put the service model section in the config file of the consuming application. DLLs always use the configuration file of the calling application, at least in my experience.

Comment: DON'T! Just DON'T call a web service from INSIDE the database. First of all, you will block your transaction for many seconds, causing any locks taken to wait for far too long and result in widespread blocking deadlocks, and all the nice things that happen when you keep locks for a long time. Then, the ".config" you are looking for is the ".config" of the SQL Server executable, if such a thing exists. It's far easier to use a separate service to do such things and call the database whenever you want to deal with data. If you must, use Service Broker to make the calls asynchronously

Comment: What can be the solution then ? Because it's the database which need to call Webservice, and not a webservice which will be call the database...

Comment: @BaptX - Rather than asking what the solution is, let's start at why you want the database to call the web service.  Are you trying to import data?  Are you trying to export data?

Comment: Because the database IS the heart of the solution. Database send datas to webservice. If it have to receive datas, we have webservices which wil connect to DB to save datas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for the solution, I followed the way of Ben Robinson.

The target of this DLL will never change, or only few times.

So I put bindings in code :

```
        [...]    

        serv = new WS_Generic.ServiceClient(ConfigureBinding(), ConfigureEndPointAddress());

        [...]


        private static EndpointAddress ConfigureEndPointAddress()
        {
            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("xxx");

            return endpointAddress;
        }

        private static BasicHttpBinding ConfigureBinding()
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

            binding.AllowCookies = false;
            binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
            binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = 5242880;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5242880;
            binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
            binding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IService";
            binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:10:00");
            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00"); ;
            binding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
            binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;

            return binding;
        }
```

And it works now ! Only one problem remains : I have to recompile the dll when I want to change the target !

Thanks for all your advice :)

Comment: And now you can deal with the blocking and deadlocks caused when the web service call blocks your transaction ... Besides, the original answer said to store the config info in a table, not hard-code it

Comment: You're right. But there are no advantage to put config in database, as I said before : the configuration will never change.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing code that lives in a dB.

Why not pass in the endpoint URL as a parameter which is stored in the dB.

Comment: That's not a stupid idea, but the objective is to find why my config file is like a ghost :) But thanks for the idea. The problem is to save all parameters of endpoints -_-

Comment: .net clr DLLs will never pick up anything in a config file.

Comment: Yup, but it quite difficult to understand at beginning :)